# Set thread`s current culture/uiculture is not considered by asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a asp.net core mvc project.

**startup.cs**

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
  new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
  new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,                       // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures                   // UI strings that we have localized.
});
```

**MyActionFilter.cs**

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{ 
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(user.CountryCode);
```

}

`CountryCode` has the value `"en-GB"` or `"de-DE"`

I am using @Resource.MyKey in the razor files.

In my ManageController.Index action I am returning a view where I update the country code "de-DE" to "en-GB", save the new value to the database...

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(RegionViewModel regionViewModel)
        {
            var user = HttpContext.GetUser();
            user.TimeZone = regionViewModel.SelectedTimeZone;
            user.CountryCode = regionViewModel.SelectedCountryCode;   
           await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)); 
        }
```

... and return to my project controller index view, but still the UI shows german localized text.

Why is that? Did I forget something to configure?

Comment: Hey Kiran will there still be a proper fix where I do not have an empty OnResourceExecuted method? Furthermore I need an async OnResourceExecuting method...

Comment: You can always have multiple resource filters. Its just that you would need the filter I specified executed before any of your resource filters.

Comment: Sorry Kiran but I do not get your answer how does it match to my question . Would you mind rephrase it again please?